# How to use integerFromInt from GHC.Num.Integer in Haskell

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm new in Haskell. I'm trying to use integerFromInt from GHC.Num.Integer.
I tried to write `integerFromInt` without `import GHC.Num.Integer`
and I got
`Variable not in scope: integerFromInt :: Int -> Integer`

I tried to write `integerFromInt` with `import GHC.Num.Integer`
and I got

```
  Could not find module ‘GHC.Num.Integer’
    Perhaps you meant GHC.Integer (from integer-gmp-1.0.3.0)
```

I think I have to add something to cabal file, but I don't know what

Comment: I don't think there is a `integerFromInt` function. You have `fromIntegral` and `fromInteger`, iirc.

Comment: `integerFromInt` is a function of `ghc-bignum` package. Instead, `toInteger` should work.

Comment: I see @Abastro thank you for letting me know

Comment: In general, stay away from the `GHC.Something` modules -- they are mostly meant for low-level primitives you are not supposed to call directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use exactly that function, then [its documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-bignum-1.2/docs/GHC-Num-Integer.html#v:integerFromInt) indicates that it comes from the `ghc-bignum` package. You can see this in the URL or by scrolling to the top of the page and looking in the top left. So you would need to add `build-depends: ghc-bignum`, preferably with a version constraint like `build-depends: ghc-bignum ^>=1.2` or whatever, to the appropriate component(s) in your cabal file.

...but in most cases, the correct answer is to use `toInteger` (or `fromIntegral`) instead, both available without imports and without adding anything to your cabal file.